# Install other OS than DSM on Synology DiskStation DS16SE — possible?

Tags: linux, installation, nas, operating-systems, synology-diskstation

The DS216SE will eventually reach its end of support. [EDIT: it is not as soon as triggered this question originally,* but that only postpones the issue. Also I'd prefer a less restricted access.]

Are there options to install an alternative OS? Preferably a Linux flavour, or a BSD variant. It should not run as a virtual machine within Synology's DiskStation Manager.

The DS216SE is built around the `ARMv7` (`32-bit`, `800MHz`) in a `Marvell Armada 370 88F6707` SoC with `256MB` RAM.

The desired functionality is file server, maybe media server.

Is that possible? Not a dumb idea for some reason?

How to proceed to install the OS? E.g., how to make the DS216SE boot into a installer USB? Windows or Linux machine available if needed.

=========

*For the upcoming DSM 7, the cutoff between unsupported/supported is between ds213 and ds214se. Similar support duration for ds216se places support end at 2023.

Comment: Have you visited this page? "How Can I Update to the Latest DSM Version From an Older Version" https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General_Setup/How_can_I_update_to_the_latest_DSM_version_from_an_older_version

Comment: Yes, am running the currently latest DSM version. New info that support probably will exist until 2023 has been edited into the question. Still I would like to have less restricted access.

Comment: You might be better to your question here at Stack Exchange 
__Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations__ 
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Please note that troubleshooting questions about installing software are off-topic, but might be asked on our sister site Super User." [About tag "installer"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/installer/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prolonged web search found only attempts that stalled when it came to reverse engineering or circumventing the SATA DOM of DiskStations, but haven't succeeded.

The DS216SE has a `MX 25L6406E` serial storage that is likely to be the boot rom. Reading from and writing to it is not too difficult, but reverse engineering its content is beyond the scope of the project, so:

Not doable without deeper knowledge (for the time being).